# Выбрать дубликаты из таблицы и потом удалить их Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно составить подзапрос для Delete, где выбираются номера клиентов - дубликатов, которые нужно удалить

Таблица и ее поля:
Таблица CLIENT – данные об абонентах.

- N_CLIENT – лицевой счет
- C_FIRST_NAME – имя
- C_SECOND_NAME – отчество
- C_LAST_NAME – фамилия
- N_SEX – идентификатор пола
- N_CITY – идентификатор города или поселка
- N_STREET – идентификатор улицы
- C_HOUSE – номер дома и номер корпуса
- N_FLAT – номер квартиры
- N_PHONE – номер телефона

Сам подзапрос:

select n_client 
from new_client_mt4
where (c_first_name, c_second_name, c_last_name, n_sex) in (select c_first_name,c_second_name, c_last_name, n_sex
                                                     from new_client_mt4
                                                     group by c_first_name, c_second_name, c_last_name, n_sex having count(*)>1)

Данный подзапрос верен, но при вставке его в delete он удалит все, и дубликат и оригинал, не смог придумать, как отделить при дубликатах оригинального клиента и не удалять его

Comment: т.е. если полный тёзка встречается, то его тоже надо удалять? ;-)

Comment: А что не так с самим подзапросом? Или с ним что-то нужно сделать?

Comment: Проблема во `WHERE (3 fields) IN (4 fields)`.

Comment: И имейте ввиду, после того как вы уберете `count(*)` из части select подзапроса вы удалите все найденные записи для которых существовали дубли, т.е. в БД не останется ни одной такой записи. убедитесь, что вы именно этого хотели. обычно при удалении дублей один экземпляр все таки оставляют ...

Comment: И да, ошибка ORA-00979 это очень странно. она должна была бы быть другой.

Comment: А есть тогда альтернативный способ реализации выбора дубликатов в подзапросе?

Comment: Что значит "альтернативный", что не так с текущим (поправленным) подзапросом

Answer (score 1):

Следующий запрос вернет вам `ORA_ROWID` строк дупликатов:

```
with vtab as (
    select
        ora_rowid as row_id,
        c_first_name, c_second_name, c_last_name,
        row_number()
        over(partition by c_first_name, c_second_name, c_last_name order by c_last_name, c_first_name, c_second_name) as rn
    from client
)
select row_id from vtab where rn > 1;
```

Далее можно удалять из `client` по `ORA_ROWID`

Но проверять уникальность по ФИО владельца счета - в корне не правильно. Надо найти другой критерий уникальности записи...

Comment: Спасибо, появился новый вопрос, как удалять их так, чтобы оставался один среди дубликатов?

Comment: И Ваш вариант выдает ошибку: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @АнтонШаронов, я немного изменил запрос - попробуйте так...